# Zend: Rollback a commit?

Tags: postgresql, zend-framework

Let's say I start a transaction and then finish it with a commit:

```
$db->beginTransaction();
// sql insert
// another sql insert
// a sql update
// another sql update
$db->commit();
```

Is there a function I can run after commit() to revert all the changes made by between beginTransaction and commit() ?

Answer (score 1):

After commit you cannot revert changes for reverting you should call `rollback` instead.

Rollback action done mainly if any one entity in a transaction fails.Therefore to catch a failure you should use `try{}catch{}`

```
$db->beginTransaction();
 try{
         $db->commit();//writes all data to database and reach to new state
 }catch(Exception $e)
  {
      $db->rollback();//roll back all changes made to database 
      echo  $e->getTraceAsString();
 }
```

Comment: But what if I want to rollback even if no exception occurred?

Comment: why you want to do that can you explain the condition when you want to roll back?

Answer (score 0):

This will revert changes from the current transaction:

```
$db->rollBack();
```

However, you cannot rollback after you have committed.

If you are trying to prevent inserting on errors etc. I would try this:

```
try
{
    $db->beginTransaction();
    // sql insert
    // another sql insert
    // a sql update
    // another sql update
    $db->commit();

}
catch( Zend_Exception $e)
{
    $db->rollBack();
}
```

This will commit if there are no errors, and rollback if there are.

Comment: No, I want a way to commit, and then rollback when I'm done. I.e. I want to make a change, TEST this change and see if I got the result I expected, and then revert that change.

Comment: A commit to the database is final.  There is no way to rollback changes made after a commit.  The only way to "Undo" the changes is to keep track of the records you changed and individually update/delete them so the data is back to the way it was originally.